# Transplanting history onto the *current* branch

Tags: git

I know how to use `git rebase --onto` to transplant history. However, I often find myself wanting to transplant history from a different branch onto my *current* branch, without the intermediate detached HEAD state.

In other words:

```
git checkout foo
git rebase --onto foo A^ B
# results in a detached HEAD
# how to avoid this last step?
git checkout -B foo
```

Comment: do you need to rebase? why not do a merge instead?

Comment: @ochi Merge won't work for this case AFAIK. I'm transplanting commit range `A` to `B` as `foo' A' ... B'` to produce `foo`, not merging in another branch. Happy to be proven wrong though :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Use `git cherry-pick`, and (later), `git reset` or `git branch -f` as appropriate.

#### Long

Bear with me for a bit while I review things you already know, since they will make the answer much clearer.

Rebase works by *copying* commits.  That is, given a commit graph of the form:

```
...--o--*--I   <-- mainline
         \
          F--G--H   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

we often find ourselves wanting to have the commit sequence `F-G-H` come *after* commit `I` on the main line.  To do that, we run `git checkout branch && git rebase mainline`, which *copies* commits `F-G-H` to new and improved ones.  Then, having made the copies, it moves the *current branch name* to point to the last such copy:

```
             F'-G'-H'  <-- branch (HEAD)
            /
...--o--*--I   <-- mainline
         \
          F--G--H   [abandoned, sort of]
```

As you already know, we can separate the set-of-commits-to-be-copied from the point-at-which-they-should-land using `git rebase --onto`.  For instance, instead of copying all of `F-G-H`, we might like to leave `F` behind, copying only `G` and `H`:

```
             G'-H'  <-- branch (HEAD)
            /
...--o--*--I   <-- mainline
         \
          F   <-- ???
           \
            G--H   [abandoned, sort of]
```

When we do this, it's a good idea to attach some name to the commit(s) we are leaving behind *before* we have Git move the name `branch`.  We can do that using `git branch`, for instance, or `git checkout -B`, or whatever.  The key, however, is that we use `--onto` to select commit `I`—the target commit after which the copies will go—and the other argument to limit which commits get copied.  The commits that *are* copied are those *after* the argument we give, up to and including the one on the `HEAD` branch.

The arguments for this `--onto` case look like:

```
git rebase --onto $target $stop
```

where `$stop` is, e.g., commit `F`.

#### How rebase works internally

The way rebase actually achieves this is pretty simple:

1. It remembers the current branch (or for a detached HEAD, hash ID): `saved_branch=$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD)`, more or less.
2. It lists the hash IDs of the commits to be copied.  It uses `git rev-list` with a lot of fancy options for this, to handle all the hard cases, but for our easy cases, we can just use `$stop..HEAD`.
3. It runs `git checkout --detach $onto` (or something more or less equivalent).
4. It runs `git cherry-pick <saved list>`, i.e., `git cherry-pick $stop..$saved_branch`.
5. Once all the cherry picks are complete—including any stops to resolve conflicts, handled by the human—it runs `git branch -f $saved_branch HEAD` (or something more or less equivalent) to make the saved branch name point to the last copied commit.  (There's also a bit of mucking-about with the special name `ORIG_HEAD`.)

#### What you want

In your case, you are already at the `--onto` part.  That is, step 1 is irrelevant, and step 2 cannot happen quite the same way.  Step 3 should not happen at all—we want the new commits to grow the current branch!

That leaves us with just steps 4 and 5 to achieve.

Step 4 is particularly easy in any modern Git, where `git cherry-pick` can handle a sequence: we just run:

```
git cherry-pick $stop..$branch
```

where `$stop` is the stop-at commit (the commit we *don't* want copied), and `$branch` is the branch that points to the last commit that we *do* want copied.  If we are on `mainline` now, that's `git cherry-pick <hash-of-F>..branch` or `git cherry-pick branch~2..branch`, to copy commits `G` and `H`.

To achieve step 5—to make `$branch` point back to commit `F`—we will leave this for later, after our copies are done.  When those copies *are* done, we can either run:

```
git checkout $branch && git reset --hard $stop
```

or:

```
git branch -f $branch $stop
```

while we're on `mainline`.

Comment: Thanks. The fact that cherry-pick accepts a range was what I needed to know... the answer to my question was therefore: `git cherry-pick A..B`.

Answer (score 0):

@torek's answer is excellent, but I wanted to post the TL;DR; to the question I specifically asked, which is:

`git cherry-pick A..B`

The key information from @torek's answer being, of course, that `cherry-pick` accepts a range.